# SubDataSet in iReport

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to use multiple queries in my report. But the main report allows me only one main query, however, I have found a way to have multiple queries in my report and that is done by subdataset in *iReport*. But I am unable to access the fields of my subdataset in my main-report. How to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

To view your sub data set you must use it in a chart, list, table etc.

Here is a great explanation:

[Multiple queries in a single jasper document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482412/multiple-queries-in-a-single-jasper-document)