# JasperReports: Executing multiple sql queries in report

Tags: sql, jasper-reports

I have one query defined above in *querystring*, I need to execute second query as select COM_NAME from company.

```xml
<subDataset name="dataset1"/>
<parameter name="toomonthyear" class="java.lang.String"/>
<parameter name="frommonthyear" class="java.lang.String"/>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[select atr_acc_com_id MGMT_COM_ID,atr_for_con_id CONTACT_ID,
concat(trim(c.CON_FIRST_NAME),' ',trim(c.CON_LAST_NAME)) CONTACT_NAME,
sum(atr_total_amount) - IFNULL((select sum(ftr_amount) from financial_trnasactions t  

where t.FTR_ATR_ID = a.atr_id),0) DEBIT_SUM
 from accounting_transactions a, invoices i, contact_details c
 where ATR_DATE between '2013-09-02' and '2013-09-02'
 and atr_acc_com_id = 1015 and
 i.inv_atr_id = a.atr_id
 AND a.ATR_FOR_CON_ID = c.con_id and
 i.inv_state  = 2
  group by atr_acc_com_id,atr_for_con_id;]]>
</queryString>
```

Please suggest the way to achieve this..

Comment: What is a reason? Can you modify the original query to get this data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple queries in a single jasper document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482412/multiple-queries-in-a-single-jasper-document)

Comment: @GenericJon First of all I can not execute 2 queries using jasper report If my second query would be <queryString>
  <![CDATA[select co.COM_NAME,co.COM_ADDR_1,co.COM_CITY, co.COM_PHONE
from  company co where co.COM_ID=1002]]>
 </queryString>                                                            
then how can i execute both queries in a single report?

Comment: @AlexK First of all I can not execute 2 queries using jasper report If my second query would be <queryString> <![CDATA[select co.COM_NAME,co.COM_ADDR_1,co.COM_CITY, co.COM_PHONE from company co where co.COM_ID=1002]]> </queryString>   then how can i execute both queries in a single report?

Comment: @MaheshPachpande You did not answer my question. Did you have any key for *company* table in *financial_trnasactions* fields? In other words have this two tables relation?