# Jasper Report run different query based on different dynamic values

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have three different queries and want to run them as per value get in jasper report.Queries are written in Jrxml file itself.How I can run different queries based on different dynamic values.

Like (It is just a sudo code)

```
 If($(a) == "Germany")

   run query 1
 If($(a) == "India")
   run query 2
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Is fields returning from query1 and query2 are different?

Comment: yes actually fields and there values are different abd based on the fields query is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define parameter `$P{a}` in **mainReport.jrxml**

Make subreports **subreport1.jrxml** (query1), **subreport2.jrxml** (query2)

Put subreport1 and subreport2 into **Title** band of mainReport.jrxml

Use PrintWhenExpression in mainReport for properties of subreports (Window->Properties)

Set PrintWhenExpression in mainReport for subreport1: `$P{a}.equals("Germany")`
Set PrintWhenExpression in mainReport for subreport2: `$P{a}.equals("India")`

Pass `$P{a}` into mainReport from your application

Comment: I have a small doubt. Does this signify that for N such queries to be executed we have to create new sub reports ??..

Comment: Another way is using subdataset. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482412/multiple-queries-in-a-single-jasper-document
But subdataset have some limitations, AFAIR

Answer (score 2):

You can try using DynamicReports. This is a library based on JasperReports, and let's you construct your report directly from you java code. 
Here is an axample [Dynamic Reports](http://www.mkyong.com/java/reporting-in-java-using-dynamicreports-and-jasperreports/)
There is a .setDataSource() method which can take a string + a connection objects. Based on some little logic you can set the query there. 
.setDataSource() is overloaded, and it can even take a ResultSet object. So you can even use a Statement/PreparedStatement object passing different queries and values, and then passing their result as a source for the report.
Hope it helps!

P.S: The example uses maven dependencies, but you can also download the .jar and add it to your classpath to make it work